Can the Nikon SB-700 Speedlight be activated off camera on a Nikon Z8 camera with the Nikon WR-R11a Wireless Remote Controller in the 10 pin port
I have Z8 camera, WR-R11a transmitter, SB-5000, SB-910 and SB-700 speedlights.
My Z8 Camera with the WR-R11a is wirelessly connected to the SB-5000 speedlight. However, I cannot figure out how to wirelessly connect my SB-910 and SB-700 along with my SB-5000.
Was hoping to set it up so that when I press the Z8 camera button to capture a picture, all 3 speedlights flash at the same time.

Here's the problem:
Your Nikon WR-11Ra Wireless Remote Controller operates wirelessly using radio signals.
Your Nikon SB-5000 is capable of being controlled remotely via wireless radio or via wireless optical control. It can also act as a wireless radio Master flash when attached to your camera's hot shoe, but it is not capable of being a wireless optical Master flash.
Your Nikon SB-910 & SB-700 are only capable of being controlled remotely via wireless optical control.
This page at Nikon explains the differences between the two systems and how they might be used together.
If you want to control and adjust the power of each flash from the camera's control menu, whether using manual power or TTL:
Basically, you need to use the WR-11Ra attached to the 10-pin connector to control your remote SB-5000 via radio and another optical controller mounted to the hot shoe to control the SB-910 & SB-700. The optical controller can be an SB-xxx flash with optical Master capability or it can be an infrared optical transmitter such as the SU-800. The optical flashes are in Groups A, B, & C on your camera's flash menu, and the radio flashes are in Groups D, E, & F.
If you're willing to "set and forget" the manual power level, zoom setting, etc. of the SB-700 & SB-910 AND use the SB-5000 only in manual mode with no pre-flashes:
You can always just put the SB-700 & SB-910 in "dumb" slave mode and they'll (hopefully) react to the light (if it's bright enough and line-of-sight) from the SB-5000 and fire as well. You'll need to make any changes directly using the SB-700 & SB-910 control panels, rather than your camera's flash settings menu.

The easiest answer is to place the SB700 and SB910 into SU4 mode (optical trigger). Then when you fire the camera via the WR-R11a it will fire the SB5000 wirelessly. The SB910 and SB700 will see the flash from the SB5000 and fire as well.
All flashes will need to be in manual mode... TTL pre-flashes will trigger the flashes that are in SU-4 mode.

No, it cannot. The WR-R11a is a radio transmitter in Nikon's AWL/CLS system.
But only the SB-5000 has built in radio remote control in this system. Both the SB-910 and SB-700 do not have any radio capability. And Nikon doesn't offer an add-on radio receiver unit to attach to the foot of an SB speedlight to bring it into this radio system.
However, all three of your speedlights have built-in optical (light signal based) AWL/CLS wireless capability. So you could use any one of your three speedlights on-camera as a "smart" optical commander unit to remotely fire, adjust power settings by group, and use iTTL and FP/HSS flash with the off-camera units.
The main drawback with optical is that most systems will lose range and reliability the brighter the ambient light is, because that can overpower the light signals used. And line-of-sight restrictions (the light sensor on the side of the speedlight has to be able to "see" the commander's signals) become more stringent when used outside without any bounce surfaces around. In short, optical works best in studio conditions, not outside on location in the daytime.
All three of your speedlights also have SU-4 mode, which is "dumb" optical slaving, that can only communicate the signal to fire. But can be used with any flash, even a pop-up flash or a built-in flash on a compact camera, as the "commander". But there won't be any TTL, FP/HSS, zoom, or group remote control over your flashes. Power and zoom have to be set manually on the flash units themselves, and you have to stay at or below sync speed.
You can, of course, also purchase a 3rd party radio transmitter and use add-on receivers (if they exist) in that system to remotely control them. For example, a Godox X3-N transmitter would work with all three of your speedlights if their feet were attached to the hotshoes on Godox X1R-N receivers. But it might make more sense to sell off the speedlights you can let go of, and replace them with Godox speedlights instead, which have built-in radio transceivers in Godox's 2.4GHz "X" radio system.
